# MySQL - Creating a user and specifying a password

Tags: mysql

How do I create a user and specify a password in one line:

I thought *CREATE USER 'foo'@'2.2.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';* would do it but apparently it doesn't.

Any thoughts? I'm on version 5.1.49 of MySQL.

Comment: I am curious what you mean "apparently it doesn't"...your command should create the user (with only the ability to log on from 2.2.2.2 and no other privileges)...so why do you say it doesn't create it?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is the good one :

```
[root@localhost] [(none)] mysql> CREATE USER 'foo'@'2.2.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

You can see if your user is created by using :

```
[root@localhost] [(none)] mysql> show grants for 'foo'@'2.2.2.2';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@2.2.2.2                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'2.2.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it'll work only if you connect from 2.2.2.2.

Max.

Comment: you ... really didn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh really? Sorry about that! He asked for how to create a user with a password, i did. Next i gave my opinion on his 2.2.2.2 and finaly i asked him his exact problem...

Comment: clarification: `How do I create a user and specify a password in one line:`

Comment: By using "identified by" option in your command : CREATE USER 'foo'@'2.2.2.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';

Comment: So in other words, you can't set the password when you create the user, but you can find the password that was assigned when the user was created?

Comment: So far your answer deviates from the actual question by `show grants for foo@2.2.2.2` and `what's the exact problem`. Nothing else that you've supplied thus far addressed the actual question, except that you could have ***commented*** "you can just get the default password for this user by running a command" ...

Comment: Man, if you dont read what iam saying, i cant help you. I think its preatty clear... If you want to create user and assignes its password in ONE command (or line...) use thé same syntaxe that he used in his question : create user max@'%' identified by 'mypass'

Comment: Ok, let's try again. The question _states_ that he tried that, and it didn't let him use the _password_ that he provided. Therefore, he's asking _why_ it didn't work. It's entirely possible that he _actually_ supplied 2.2.2.2, but I bet that's shorthand-example, just as foo and bar are. Maybe what you meant to do was to leave a comment on the question asking what the exact error is?

Comment: Looking at this, I can say you are pretty close. However, there is another method. Your command works but is functionally incomplete. The user can login after the user's creation but that's all. Your `SHOW GRANTS` reveals that. Since mysql's default sql_mode allows non-ANSI stuff, you could pull it off the GRANT command. That will do three things: 1) create the user, 2) set the password, 3) set the privs IN ONE COMMAND. Check the MySQL Doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html . It says if `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` is set, two commands needed. Otherwise, the one GRANT can do it.

Comment: I am going to give you a +1 for what you contributed because doing this in one command is not widely known unless one is fully aware of MySQL's non-ANSI shortcuts and caveats. As written, you answer does answer the question as posed in its context.

Answer (score 1):

For the change is applied immidiately, you must use **flush privileges** to flush all memory cache of user table. Finally, you should make sure your client is 2.2.2.2

Comment: There is no need to do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` if you use the `CREATE USER` or `GRANT` keywords, only if you directly modify the mysql.* tables.

Comment: Right! In the case, flush privileges is redundancy. I have read it "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html"